# Codeigniter CLI Controller mishap

Tags: database, codeigniter, cron, command-line-interface

So i followed this tutorial

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/cli.html

and i tried doing

```
   php index.php tools message
```

but i'm getting this error in terminal:

```
   <h1>A Database Error Occurred</h1>
   <p>Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.</p>
   <p>Filename:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/470repo/projects/main/development/CodeIgniter/third_party/MX/Loader.php</p>
   <p>Line Number: 98</p>
```

I need this in order to bake assets using the Sprinkle library from https://github.com/edmundask/Sprinkle/wiki/Baking-assets
I've been looking around the forum, but I can't find a specific solution to this problem. So, i am in need to saving.

I'm using php version 5.3.1 and the latest version of codeigniter.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks! :)

Comment: Try `var_dump($params)` on line 96ish in the MX loader and see what DB connection settings it's trying to use.

Answer (score 7):

Are you working from local?

If yes, try changing the hostname from

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
```

to this:

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = '127.0.0.1';
```

Comment: +1 worked for me too. Is there a reason why this behaviour occurs?

Answer (score 0):

It seems he can't connect to your database. Did you check your database settings in the database.php config file if it's correct?

If you are using multiple environments, check the part where you set your environment. Maybe he picks the wrong one.

You can also enable logs in the config.php file and check those.